# Gzip a tar file in python

Tags: python, tar, gzip

Is there an easy way to gzip a tar file in python so when I unzip, I can directly get the contents? I can create a gzipped file from a tar file but on untaring I still get the tar file rather than contents.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the good people at [link to the docs here.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tarfile.html)

#### getting info out of a tar.gz file

```
import tarfile
with tarfile.open("sample.tar.gz", 'r:gz') as tfile:
   with tfile.extractfile('somedir/somefile.txt') as target_file:
       data = target_file.read()
```

#### getting info into a tar.gz file

```
import tarfile
with tarfile.open('sample.tar.gz','w:gz') as tar:
    tar.add('dir_or_file')
```

Comment: I will give this a try. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Yes, but this is a system issue, not Python.

```
tar -xzf <tar_zip_file>
```

The **-z** flag works on creation, as well.

Comment: I  know that, but I need a way to do it in python. I could do:
````f_in = open('M.tar', 'rb')
f_out = gzip.open('M.tar.gz', 'wb')
f_out.writelines(f_in)````

Just wanted to see if there is a better way than this!